# How to remove "sign out" button

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I'm using a kiosk software where the user is getting a blank desktop when he signs out from SharePoint and closes the browser so I don't want the users to sign out.

How can I remove the "sign out" button using css and/or javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use

```
#welcomeMenuBox li[onmenuclick*="SignOut.aspx"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove/hide it by using CSS

```
#mp1_0_1
 {
   display:none !important;

 }
```

Comment: SharePoint 2013, not O365/SharePoint online

Comment: it works for SP2016

Comment: @jlai79 I've update my solution to work for SP2013

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve it:

```
<style>

a[title='Sign Out']
{
    display:none !important;
}

</stype>
```

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Comment: This works only for one language. Please keep in mind that the world is bigger than than one single `lcid`